# trying to send e-mail addreses to two recipient

Tags: php

Mon Apr 02, 2012 9:11 am
please i am trying to send email to two recipient, one is in the database and the other is not i have tried this two syntax but they re not working

```
$to = "$email,another@stack.com";
and
$to = $email, "another@stack.com";
```

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer Library for sending emails with PHP.

Comment: @Basti please have not been able to figure it out

Comment: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsendmail

Comment: Ugh, that library uses some horrible naming conventions. a method called `IsWhatever()` should **not** have side-effects. People expect a getter behind such a name.

Answer (score 3):

Simply pass a semicolon-separated list:

```
$to = "a@b.com; c@d.com";
```

Note however that both recipients will see both adresses. If you do not want this, add the second recipient as BCC (pass `BCC: c@d.com` as an additional header to `mail()`)

Comment: i tried it but neither of the recipient got the mail,hope the $email (this would be pulled from a database)is not affecting the syntax

Comment: i have resorted using the blind carbon copy